# How to modify a z3c form field in updateWidgets?

Tags: forms, plone, zope, z3c.form

I am trying to dynamically update a form field based on a variable that is included in a HTTP get variable. Specifically www.site.com/form?id=name. I want to pull the 'id' field from the url and automatically populate the memberID field of the form.

I have access to the get variable using self.request.get('id'). However I haven't been able to figure out how to update the form field. I examined the widget documentation http://packages.python.org/z3c.form/widget.html but none of the suggestions have worked.

```
class IUpdateEmailFormSchema(interface.Interface):
    # -*- extra stuff goes here -*-
    """
    """
    memberID = schema.TextLine(title=(u'Member id'))

    email = schema.TextLine(title=(u'Email'), description=(u'The email'))

class updateEmailForm(form.Form):
    fields = field.Fields(IUpdateEmailFormSchema)
    label = _(u'Change Email')
    ignoreContext = True


    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Update')
    def handleUpdate(self,action):
        data, errors = self.extractData()

        if data.has_key('email'):

            portal_membership = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_membership')
            member = portal_membership.getMemberById(data['memberID'])

    def updateWidgets(self):
        print "This is update widget \n\n"
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        print self.request.form['id']    #Does not work as specified in http://packages.python.org/z3c.form/widget.html
        #self.widgets["memberID"].value = self.request.get('id').encode('utf-8')
        form.Form.updateWidgets(self)

updateEmailFormView = wrap_form(updateEmailForm)
```

*Update: updateWidget wasn't correctly indented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

updateWidgets method is the right place to do it.
just you shouuld first call "form.Form.updateWidgets" and then do your 
changes (even better user super() as shown bellow):

```
def updateWidgets(self):
    super(updateEmailForm, self).updateWidgets()
    id = self.request.get('id', None)
    if id:
        self.widgets["memberID"].value = id.encode('utf-8')
```

so basically the error was the order

and if there is no request (which is kinda weird and you are probably doing something worng there) then you can get it [via](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/five.globalrequest):

```
from zope.globalrequest import getRequest
request = getRequest()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rok. I implemented your suggestion and made some progress. The value of the form field memberID now does in fact get updated with the correct ID, but when the page renders it is NOT populated with the ID. I confirmed with pdb that the value was in fact correctly changed, but the text field doesn't change when with ID. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

Your updateWigets() won't be called above because it's not inside the body of the form, it's a top level function.

Also, you should use super() to call the parent version of updateWidgets() - in your case, you probably want to call the parent version first and then change the value or whatever.

You may be better off using a default value adapter instead of updateWidgets() too.

Comment: Greetings optilute. Thanks for your suggestions. A few points though. 1. I edited the original code. For some reason updateWidget wasn't properly indented when I copied it over. 2. The updateWidgets function DOES in fact run. I have tested it with print lines on the terminal. Moreover, the Plone documentation (http://collective-docs.plone.org/forms/z3c.form.html#modifying-a-widget) recommends that one puts the update function in this place. So i'm not sure if you met something else. 2. Even if I do call the parent function, what would be the accessor I use to modify the field? 3. Could you...

Comment: I didn't understand the default value suggestion. The self.request is not defined within the scope of the form schema definition. How would I access it?